# How to insert values into an already existing table in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

I have an already existing table in postgresql called order_facts.

Running `select * from order_facts` gets you [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X53dw.png):
as you can see order_date is null and I'd like to populate it with data from another table.
To do that i used the following code:

```
insert into order_facts(order_date)
select day_key
from "Day" as d, orders as o
where d.fulldate = o.order_date;
```

But this appends the day_key values at the bottom of the table [like so](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MryU.png)
What do I change in my insert command to get it to start inserting the day_key from row 1 and not the end of the row?

Comment: use [UPDATE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-update.html) instead of INSERT

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use `UPDATE` instead of `INSERT`.

e.g.

```
update order_facts
set order_date = d.day_key
from "Day" as d, orders as o
where d.fulldate = o.order_date
and order_facts.order_id = o.order_id
```